# Session timing out too soon with CakePHP 2.0

Tags: session, cakephp-2.0

I recently switched over to Cake2.0, and was having some issues with Sessions timing out much sooner than they should.

Copying the example from the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html#built-in-session-handlers-configuration), I set the session type to php, and set the timeout to 3 days (4320 mins). However, after reading various articles, it seems that even after setting the timeout to 3 days in Cake, PHP may destroy the session in GC if  PHP.ini is set with a shorter timeout for the session or GC.

So, I changed the Session default to cake, with the same timeout.

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
   'defaults' => 'cake',
   'timeout' => 4320,
));

Configure::write('Security.level', 'medium');
```

However, while this should leave me logged in for 3 days, I find I barely get 3 hours before I need to log in again.

Is there an issue with Session timeouts that I should be aware of, or is the timeout in seconds (not minutes?) or is it being influenced by the Security.level like in 1.3? I haven't been able to find any hard documentation about how this works in 2.0, or what could be causing the issues.

Thanks in advance.

**Answer:**
For anyone coming in later and seeing this. There is a bug in 2.0.5 where the Session timeout was not saving the value in Config.write();

To solve, update to 2.0.6 (or 2.1 when it leaves beta)

Comment: Nice to know! Thanks for updating your question with the solution.

Comment: Weird, I'm still getting this bug in 2.0.6...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the security component, you can always try changing the expiration on them to 3 hours as well:

```
$components = array(
    'Security' => array(
        'csrfExpires' => '+3 hour'
    )
);
```

I am not saying this is a good idea to do, but it could help you narrow down the problem. If you are using the Security component, this is probably the issue.

Also, the Session.timeout is in minutes (not seconds).